# How to change control panel settings in python script?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, registry, mouse

Basically in my script I am trying to edit the control panel setting that affects how fast the mouse scrolls. I tried using

`import subprocess
subprocess.call("reg add \"HKCU\\Control Panel\\Desktop\" /v WheelScrollLines /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f")`

which successfully changes the registry according to regedit, however the setting doesn't actually change as reflected in control panel where it stays at 3. I think this is because there may be a reboot required for the change to take effect. However, you can obviously change the value through control panel without restarting so I was wondering if there was a solution.

Comment: AFAIK, you need to relogin to activate HKCU changes made through reg.exe. There are hacks if you do a web search for this command. But this is probably something that can be researched over at https://superuser.com/ (as this isn't _really_ a coding question, but rather about a specific Windows command).

Comment: Also, you might have an easier time doing this on `Powershell` instead, but really depends what you are trying to achieve at the end.